# Conditional Probability Question Given P(H), P(D), and P(H and D)

Tags: probability

We are given that $P(H)=.3$, $P(D)=.5$, and $P(H \cap D)=.2$. we want to find the probability $P(D|H)$

Here was my approach. I started by creating the below table:

[image: Probability Table]

$$P(D|H)=\frac{P(D \cap H)}{P(H)}=\frac{P(D)P(H|D)}{P(D)P(H|D)+P(D')P(H|D')}$$

I attempted this but am not coming up with the correct answer. My book says it should be $\frac{2}{3}$. I am having a hard time identifying which probabilities to use in this formula. How do I find the conditional Probabilities I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Donut over complicate things.

As you say, $\mathsf P(D\mid H)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(D\cap H)}{\mathsf P(H)}$, and you were given that $\mathsf P(D\cap H)=0.2$ and $\mathsf P(H)=0.3$.

Just put it together. $$\mathsf P(D\mid H)=\dfrac{0.2}{0.3}$$